# $cookies service equivalent to chrome.cookies?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, cookies

I'm new to angular and am working on trying to rebuild a chrome extension into a generic webapp using angular just to learn it.

One of the very first things the extension does is grab a specific cookie (created by logging into a website in a browser tab) using the command `chrome.cookies.getAll()`.  Is the angular equivalent to this just using the $cookies service with `$cookies.getAll()`? It doesn't seem to be having the same effect when I test it, which is why I ask, so I apologize if this is a stupid question.  Anyway, any guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

$cookies.getAll(); is a method that should grab all of the $cookies. Make sure you have the ngCookies module to be installed.

The ngCookies module does not come as part of the angular package. You'll have to load it separately into the header. `https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular-cookies.min.js`